# Interpretation of Gauss law for displacement field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, dielectric

I am studying Griffiths' introduction to electrodynamics and I struggle to understand the field of application of $$\int{D \cdot dA}=Q_{f_{enc}}.$$ Griffiths states that this law holds within dielectrics. Is $Q_{f_{enc}}$ the free charge inside the dielectrics (if so, could you please explain me what is the sense of having free charges in a dielectrics ?) or is it the free charge responsible for the external electric field $E$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer

The total charge is responsible for $\mathbf{e}$, the free charge is responsible for $\mathbf{d}$. How the total charge is related to the free charge, and how the dielectric field is related to the electric field depends on the properties, described by a constitutive equation, of the dielectric medium.

### Charges and fields in a dielectric

Free charge could be defined as the charge you'd have in absence of the dielectric, or the "polarizable" medium; that's it.
When you're dealing with a dielectric that "feels" and "react" to the presence of these charges, you can split the actual charge distribution as the sum of the effects of free charges and polarization. For density, you can split it as

\begin{equation}
  \rho(\mathbf{r},t) = \rho_f(\mathbf{r},t) + \rho_b(\mathbf{r},t) \
\end{equation}

while for the (di)electric field

\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{d}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r}, t) + \mathbf{p}(\mathbf{r}, t) \ , \text{or}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon_0} \mathbf{d}(\mathbf{r}, t) - \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon_0} \mathbf{p}(\mathbf{r}, t) 
\end{equation}

being the second terms ($\rho_b(\mathbf{r},t) = 0$, $\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{r},t) = \mathbf{0}$) identically zero in vacuum, or without the presence of a dielectric.

**Remark.** Please, note that $\mathbf{d}(\mathbf{r}, t)$ and $\mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r}, t)$ don't have the same physical dimensions.

**Polarization.** The response of the dielectric depends on the very nature of the medium involved. If it's a non dispersive homogeneous and isotropic linear medium, it's possible to write the constitutive equation for polarization as
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{p} = \varepsilon_0 \chi_{e} \mathbf{e} \ ,
\end{equation}
being $\chi_e$ the susceptibility of the medium, related to the relative permittivity $\chi_e = \varepsilon_r - 1$, so that the relation between the dielectric and the electric fields becomes
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{d} = \varepsilon_0 \varepsilon_r \mathbf{e} \ .
\end{equation}

### Gauss' law for $\mathbf{d}(\mathbf{r}, t)$

Gauss' law for the dielectric field $\mathbf{d}(\mathbf{r}, t)$ states that, for a volume $V$ with boundary $S = \partial V$, the total free charges enclosed in that volume $V$ equals the flux of the dielectric field through its boundary $S$,

\begin{equation}
 \Phi_{\partial V}(\mathbf{d}) = \oint_{\partial V} \mathbf{d} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} = Q_{f, V} \ ,
\end{equation}
or for continuous distribution of electric free electric charge,
\begin{equation}
  Q_{f, V} = \int_{V} \rho_{f} \ .
\end{equation}
With the assumption of "sufficient regularity of the fields $\rho_f(\mathbf{r},t)$ and $\mathbf{d}(\mathbf{r},t)$, it's possible to apply divergence theorem to transform the surface integral to a volume integral, and exploit the arbitrariness of the volume $V$, to derive the differential form of the Gauss'law for $\mathbf{d}$,

\begin{equation}
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{d} = \rho_f \ ,
\end{equation}

that is one of the Maxwell's equations.

Moreover, using the decompositions above, it's possible to write
\begin{equation}
  \nabla \cdot \left( \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e} + \mathbf{p} \right) = \rho - \rho_b \ ,
\end{equation}
and splitting the "vacuum contribution" (as it would be with no dielectric) and the "polarization contribution" as
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{e} & = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0} \\
 -\nabla \cdot \mathbf{p} & = \rho_b \ .
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

As you can see from the last three equations, the total charge density $\rho$ appears in the Gauss' law for $\mathbf{e}$ and the free charge density $\rho_f$ appears in the Gauss' law for $\mathbf{d}$, as stated in the "Short answer" paragraph at the beginning of this answer.

### Example: homogeneous, isotropic, linear, non-dispersive medium

Given the equations above, for a dielectric medium the following equations/relations hold,
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
  \mathbf{d} & = \varepsilon_0 \mathbf{e} + \mathbf{p} \\
  \mathbf{d} & = \varepsilon_0 \varepsilon_r \mathbf{e} \\
  \mathbf{p} & = \varepsilon_0 \chi_e \mathbf{e} \ ,
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
thus, knowing the free charge distribution $\rho_b$ and solving for
\begin{equation}
  \nabla \cdot \mathbf{d} = \rho_b \ ,
\end{equation}
it's possible to get the total electric field
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{e} = \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon_0 \varepsilon_r} \mathbf{d} \ ,
\end{equation}
that has the same direction of $\frac{\mathbf{d}}{\varepsilon_0}$ (the electric field you'd have in vacuum), but with a smaller magnitude, since $\varepsilon_r \ge 1$ (due to the response of the dielectric-bounded charges).
Then, the polarization field reads
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{p} = \varepsilon_0 \chi_e \mathbf{e} = \dfrac{\chi_e}{\varepsilon_r} \mathbf{d} = \dfrac{\varepsilon_r-1}{\varepsilon_r} \mathbf{d} \ ,
\end{equation}
and the bound charges can be evaluated, assuming uniform parameters and thus uniform medium, as
\begin{equation}
  \rho_b = - \nabla \cdot \mathbf{p} = - \dfrac{\varepsilon_r-1}{\varepsilon_r} \nabla \mathbf{d} = - \dfrac{\varepsilon_r-1}{\varepsilon_r} \rho_f \ ,
\end{equation}
while total charge density
\begin{equation}
  \rho = \rho_b + \rho_f = \left( 1 - \dfrac{\varepsilon_r-1}{\varepsilon_r} \right) \rho_f = \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon_r} \rho_f \ .
\end{equation}

### Axial-symmetric example (I): dielectric

[image]

### Axial-symmetric example (II): conductor

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! So if I do understand you, a charge distribution enclosed by a dielectrics has two types of charges density: part of it gets bounded due to polarization and part of it remains free ? Thus, the total charge remains constant and only the electric field gets attenuated ? Or does the polarization of the distribution generates opposed polarization frome the dielectrics, cancelling the bounded charges ?

Comment: I'm adding an edit at the end of my answer to clarify this points

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I'll add a small example since the treatment of discontinuities could be tricky, as surface charge distribution may occur to get an overall charge distribution consistent with the displacement, electric and polarization fields. Once you're ok with the answer, please upvote and accept.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. So, upvoting is the way we do in this forum if an answer is useful

Comment: And accepting the answer, if you're the one that asked it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151010/discussion-between-tymothee-waldner-and-basics).